# Proposal: destroy the "big-list" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I noticed, not for the first time, that a question was marked "incorrectly" with the [big-list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) tag, which has the description:

> Questions asking for a "big list" of examples, illustrations, etc. Please do not ask too many of these. Please do not use this as the only tag for a question.

I started a clean-up of this tag and I realized that *most* of the questions were using it contrary to this description.  Unless we want to redefine this tag to instead mean "my question somehow relates to big `List` expressions" I think we should blacklist it, as it is demonstrably confusing, and IMHO of questionable value even in the intended application.

**Please vote up or down on this question, up meaning kill the tag.** If you vote down please post a comment or answer explaining what you would like to see done.

Comment: I never liked `big list`-s: I always had the feeling that after reaching a certain size, no one actually checks the content anymore while many keep adding stuff to it...

Comment: @István I see that as a real danger, but I also think it depends on the type of post and the quality of the organization.