# How should "Alternatives to Mathematica" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Alternatives to Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28162/alternatives-to-mathematica) had only the [now-obsolete](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/proposal-destroy-the-big-list-tag) "big-list" tag on it.  I replaced it with [guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) but that isn't really appropriate because it is *not* about guidelines for using *Mathematica*.  How should we tag it?  Or since this question really isn't about *Mathematica* itself should it even be here?

---

I am not happy with the proposals, and no one made a compelling argument that this question really belongs here, therefore I have **Locked** it for "historical significance" which is one of the standardized reasons; I think it fits quite well:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

Comment: "External *something-or-other*"? Perhaps [tag:alternative-solutions], although that could be abused and be open to almost any Q about any computational system.  Or maybe just punt and call it [tag:untaggable] :)  I think with so many votes, we ought to be able to make room for it.  I don't have a suggestion I like.

Comment: If we decide on a [tag:comparison] [**there**](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1739/5478) then it could be it for example.

Comment: "specifically with regard to solving, manipulating and visualising algebraic expressions." <-- Maybe use this part of the question and use `symbolic`, `visualization` , etc. to avoid the introduction of new tags for such questions. Why avoid that?  Because one might argue that this question is a borderline one ... technically it might belong on SciComp.SE but in practice it may receive better responses here.  The TeX.SE equivalent question is tagged `typesetting`.

Answer (score 3):

We should create the tag [external-programs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-programs) and apply it here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [computation-systems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computation-systems)? The tag wiki should explain the tag is intended for discussions which compare *Mathematica* with competing systems.